# OpenID security, any changes to this

Tags: php, security, web-applications, openid

This is the paragraph on OpenID security from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#Security_and_phishing). Are there any new updates about this, or any comments?

> Security and phishing
>
> Some observers have suggested that
>   OpenID has security weaknesses and may
>   prove vulnerable to phishing
>   attacks.[26][27][28] For example, a
>   malicious relying party may forward
>   the end-user to a bogus identity
>   provider authentication page asking
>   that end-user to input their
>   credentials. On completion of this,
>   the malicious party (who in this case
>   also control the bogus authentication
>   page) could then have access to the
>   end-user's account with the identity
>   provider, and as such then use that
>   end-user’s OpenID to log into other
>   services.
>
> In an attempt to combat possible
>   phishing attacks some OpenID providers
>   mandate that the end-user needs to be
>   authenticated with them prior to an
>   attempt to authenticate with the
>   relying party.[29] This relies on the
>   end-user knowing the policy of the
>   identity provider. In December 2008,
>   the OpenID Foundation approved version
>   1.0 of the Provider Authentication Policy Extension (PAPE), which
>   "enables Relying Parties to request
>   that OpenID Providers employ specified
>   authentication policies when
>   authenticating users and for OpenID
>   Providers to inform the Relying
>   Parties which policies were actually
>   used."[30] Regardless, this issue
>   remains a significant additional
>   vector for man-in-the-middle phishing
>   attacks.
>
> Other security issues identified with
>   OpenID involve lack of privacy and
>   failure to address the trust
>   problem.[31]

Comment: Phishing is social engineering. Some people don't look at the obvious signs that protects against it (URL not on the provider's domain, no/doubtful SSL cert, etc.). I doubt that'll change in a lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This phishing attack still holds. If I (as a phisherman) sets up a page, I can link to my self-made (copied) Google login page and claim it's the real one. I don't even need to implement OpenID, I can just *say* that I do.

So yes, this attack is still very much possible. The solution is to educate computer users: they should check the domain name, make sure the login page uses SSL and that the SSL certificate is for the correct domain.

Comment: So I would be safer to implement normal login I guess. Do you agree?

Comment: No. Normal login pages are just as susceptible to phishing attacks. When using normal login pages you are also responsible for the users' credentials (especially the password), which you are not when using OpenID. The only thing which may be safer with normal login pages is if the user have different passwords for different sites. In that case, if your site is compromised the password is still not able to steal other accounts. Most users, however, do use the same password for different sites so the value of a phishing attack is still the same as if OpenID were used.